# How to prove $f(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the function $f$ given by

$$f(y) = \frac{y+x/y}{2}.$$

How does one prove $f(\sqrt{x}) = \sqrt{x}$?

If I plug in the square root of $x$, how do I get back to $\sqrt{x}$?  I'm looking over an MIT lecture on fixed point.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to ask.. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Check out this [link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to properly format your code in order for others to understand what you're asking.

Comment: I think this problem may be confusing because $f(y)$ is not a function of $x$.  In this case $x$ is simply a constant.  As per the answer below, just plug $\sqrt{x}$ into the equation in place of $y$ and simplify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply:

$$f(\sqrt x)=\frac{\sqrt x+\frac x{\sqrt x}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt x+\sqrt x}{2}=\sqrt x$$

Answer (score 3):

$$f(y)=\dfrac{y+\dfrac{x}{y}}{2}.$$

Hence,

$$f(\sqrt{x})=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}}}{2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}}{2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{x\sqrt{x}}{x}}{2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x}}{2}=\dfrac{2\sqrt{x}}{2}=\sqrt{x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, $f(y)=y$ iff $y=\pm \sqrt x $:
$$
y = \frac{y+x/y}{2} \iff 2y = y + x/y \iff y = x/y \iff y^2=x
$$